# how can i open a webpage in a webview from a fragment with buttons?

Tags: android, button, webview, fragment

I read the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116216/michele-la-ferla (michele la ferla) here: [how can i open a webpage in a webview from a fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446954/how-can-i-open-a-webpage-in-a-webview-from-a-fragment/26556862#26556862) 
but when you have more buttons for more URL in "layout.xml" file, 
how modify you the "fragment class" file? 
 this is my code for the first button, where is the error?:

```
   private Dialog WebDialog1;
    private WebView URL1;
    private Button button0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentsite, container, false);

        button0 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WebDialog1 = new Dialog(getActivity());
                WebDialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                WebDialog1.setContentView(R.layout.sitef);
                WebDialog1.setCancelable(true);

                URL1 = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
                URL1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                URL1.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
                URL1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                URL1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                URL1.loadUrl("http://www.dhfhfhfh.com/Home.php");

                WebDialog1.show();
            }



        });return rootView;}}'
```

Comment: I can't really understand your question. Do you have 2 buttons and want to open a different web page each time on the click of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question well, your scenario is composed of the following:

1. A layout file with more than one button.
2. Each button loads a different url in a webview.

Taking these into consideration, I would implement it using an ActionListener on each button, and sending the parameters to load the url in a webview in the ActionEvent.

Fragment event:

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

private Dialog WebDialog1, WebDialog2;
private WebView URL1, URL2;
private Button btnURL1, btnURL2;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, container, false);

    btnURL1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnURL1);
    btnURL1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WebDialog1 = new Dialog(getActivity());
            WebDialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WebDialog1.setContentView(R.layout.web_layout);
            WebDialog1.setCancelable(true);                  

            URL1 = (WebView) WebDialog.findViewById(R.id.url1);  
            URL1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            URL1.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);  
            URL1.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);  
            URL1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            URL1.getSettings().setUserAgentString("First Webview");  
            URL1.loadUrl("//the first url goes here");

            WebDialog1.show();
        }

    btnURL2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnURL2);
    btnURL2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WebDialog2 = new Dialog(getActivity());
            WebDialog2.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WebDialog2.setContentView(R.layout.web_layout);
            WebDialog2.setCancelable(true);                  

            URL2 = (WebView) WebDialog.findViewById(R.id.url2);  
            URL2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            URL2.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);  
            URL2.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);  
            URL2.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            URL2.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Second Webview");  
            URL2.loadUrl("//the second url goes here");

            WebDialog2.show();
        }

    });
    return rootView;
}
```

main_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnURL1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnURL2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

</RelativeLayout>
```

web_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.82" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Buy your Tickets:" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/ticketline"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/Title"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

While at it, I would take a look at the official Android documentation for [buttons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and [ActionListeners](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) too.

Comment: can you please accept the answer if this has helped you?

Comment: can you cancel the code relative to point 3 "In this case the Webview is loaded in a dialog, enabling the user to go back to your app on backpress."? I need only that each button loads a different url in a webview in a fragment. But why don't' you use "if " and "if also"? thanks for help me in advance....

Comment: I edited the code to get what you want. You can just copy and paste. I didn't use if statements, because code is cleaner with an actionlistener on each button.

Comment: could you please accept this question if it has helped you? Otherwise I would be more than happy to help you further.

Comment: i edited the code in the question, where is the error? why you use "WebConn", can i use "new WebViewClient"?

Comment: Dear Michele, sorry but the code not run. I corrected also this line like this "URL1 = (WebView) WebDialog1.findViewById(R.id.url1);" but when i push the button this open just one line white and dont'not open a webview with webpage. Where is the problem?

Comment: COuld you please update the question you primarily asked with the code you used till now? That way we can solve the issue much easier :)